# Search an integer in a row-sorted two dim array, is there any better approach?

Tags: c#, search, coding-style

I have recently come across with this problem, 
you have to find an integer from a sorted two dimensional array. But the two dim array is sorted in rows not in columns. I have solved the problem but still thinking that there may be some better approach. So I have come here to discuss with all of you. Your suggestions and improvement will help me to grow in coding. here is the code

```
int searchInteger = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
           if (intarry[i, 0] <= searchInteger && intarry[i,y-1] >= searchInteger)
           {
               if (intarry[i, 0] == searchInteger || intarry[i, y - 1] == searchInteger)
                  Console.WriteLine("string present {0} times" , ++cnt);
                  else
                  {
                      int[] array = new int[y];
                      int y1 = 0;
                      for (int k = 0; k < y; k++)
                      array[k] = intarry[i, y1++];
                      bool result;

                        if (result = binarySearch(array, searchInteger) == true)
                       {
                        Console.WriteLine("string present inside {0} times", ++ cnt);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                       }
                 }
           }

       }
```

Where searchInteger is the integer we have to find in the array. and binary search is the methiod which is returning boolean if the value is present in the single dimension array (in that single row).

please help, is it optimum or there are better solution than this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have declared the array `intarry`, `x` and `y` as follows:

```
int[,] intarry =
{
    {0,7,2},
    {3,4,5},
    {6,7,8}
};
var y = intarry.GetUpperBound(0)+1;
var x = intarry.GetUpperBound(1)+1; 
// intarry.Dump();
```

You can keep it as simple as:

```
int searchInteger = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

var cnt=0;
for(var r=0; r<y; r++)
{
    for(var c=0; c<x; c++)
    {
        if (intarry[r, c].Equals(searchInteger)) 
        {
            cnt++;
            Console.WriteLine(
                "string present at position [{0},{1}]" , r, c);         
        } // if
    } // for
} // for
Console.WriteLine("string present {0} times" , cnt);
```

This example assumes that you don't have any information whether the array is sorted or not (which means:  if you don't know if it is sorted you have to go through every element and can't use binary search). Based on this example you can refine the performance, if you know more how the data in the array is structured:

- if the rows are sorted ascending, you can replace the inner for loop by a binary search
- if the entire array is sorted ascending and the data does not repeat, e.g.

  > int[,] intarry = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}};

  then you can exit the loop as soon as the item is found. The easiest way to do this to create
  a function and add a return statement to the inner for loop.